# How good is Falcon to serve media files (audio, images, videos)?

Tags: python-3.x, falconframework

I've started a project in which I have to allow user to access certain content, in this case media files. I'm wondering if Falcon is good at serving this.

Example route work like this:
'/audio/{audio_id}' -> if user.has_permission(audio_id): return audio file for download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serving audio/video files in falcon is the same as serving images (they're all binary files).  See their tutorial on serving images for how to do it:

http://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/tutorial.html#serving-images

Where falcon is 'good' for it is a tricky question.   It can do it, but to determine if it is 'good' (or 'good enough' in most cases) you need benchmarks for serving files and your own performance requirements.  I was unable to find any public benchmarks for python api frameworks that include a metric for serving files.  You'll need to determine if it's good enough based on performance tests.

Also, an alternative to serving the media directly is to return a link in the api response that points to a file hosted on a CDN.  The downside to this approach is that it's less secure (anyone with the direct link can access it).

Answer (score 0):

```
   def on_get(self, req, resp, tts_text):
        res_file = './audio_after.wav' #./test.png is ok too
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200  
        resp.content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(res_file)[0]
        stream = open(res_file, 'rb')
        content_length = os.path.getsize(res_file)
        resp.stream = stream
        resp.content_length = content_length
```

Comment: this works for me. both in case of image(.png) and audio(.wav)